# BLoC approach for new Flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I will be starting new project in Flutter and I'm wondering about BLoC approach instead of Provider. **Do you know any real no hello world open source projects based on BLoC ?** I didn't find any interesting sources.

I'm Android developer so I'm coming from MVVM/Clean Architecture approach and it looks like BLoC is closer to it. Give me also yours feelings about using BLoC in Flutter comparing to Provider.

Answer (score 3):

I have created an app, using BLoC and it was a smooth experience, code is maintainable, easy to test, scalable and readable.

My experience is, we worry too much to choose the perfect solution. All of those approaches should get you through reasonably big projects, but since BLoC is more like MVVM and I am also coming from Android background, I would recommend BLoC.